# How to disable a user's password in AWS using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am auditing user passwords in AWS using boto3 and I'm not finding a way to accomplish the following CIS Benchmark: "Ensure credentials (with password enabled) unused for 90 days or greater are disabled."

I have the code to pull the password age and to pull the last time the password was used, but I do not find anything to make inactive a password.

For access keys (but not passwords), we have the following:

```
client = session.client('iam')

... (get user and keyid) ...

last_used = client.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=keyid)

... (determine the age of the key) ...

if age >= 90:

    client.update_access_key(AccessKeyId=keyid, Status='Inactive', UserName=user)
```

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the responders, delete_login_profile followed by a password reset using create_login_profile is exactly what I needed. I saw it in the docs, but "delete" just sounded too scary.

```
def getPassword(client, user):
    ''' get the password data from aws '''
    try:
        response = client.get_login_profile(UserName=user)
        return response

    except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException as e:
        print(e)
        return ''

# setup the client handler
client = session.client('iam')

# set the user
user = 'some.user'

# if the user has a password, execute this code block
if getPassword(client=client, user=user):

    ... code to test the password age here ...
    ... if it's too old, then ...

    # remove the login_profile/password/ability to use the Console
    client.delete_login_profile(UserName=user)

    # set the new password
    passwd = raw_input('Enter New Password: ')

    # create the new login_profile with the new password and force the user to change the password on the next login
    client.create_login_profile(UserName=user, Password=passwd, PasswordResetRequired=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

[delete_login_profile](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_login_profile) is the one you should use if you want to delete the password for the specified IAM user, which terminates the user's ability to access AWS services through the AWS Management Console.

**However to prevent all user access (including CLI and API access) you must also either make any access keys inactive or delete them.**

From [Boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_login_profile) Documentation:

> **Warning**
>
> Deleting a user's password does not prevent a user from accessing AWS
>   through the command line interface or the API. To prevent all user
>   access you must also either make any access keys inactive or delete
>   them. For more information about making keys inactive or deleting
>   them, see UpdateAccessKey and DeleteAccessKey.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the password, you should use `update_login_profile` boto3 API. If you want to disable the password, you need to use `delete_login_profile`.

- boto3 documentation for `update_login_profile` can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.update_login_profile).
- boto3 documentation for `delete_login_profile` can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_login_profile).